# Get content from certain tags with certain attributes using BS4

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to get the content from the following tag with these attributes: `<span class="h6 m-0">`.
An example of the HTML I'll encounter would be `<span class="h6 m-0">Hello world</span>`, and it obviously needs to return `Hello world`.

My current code is as follows:

```py
page = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
names = [item["class"] for item in page.find_all('span')]
```

This works fine, and gets me all the spans in the page, but I don't know how to specify that I only want those with the specific class `"h6 m-0"` and grab the content inside. How will I go about doing this?

Comment: `print([span.text for span in page.select('span.h6.m-0')])` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
page = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
names = page.find_all('span' , class_ = 'h6 m-0')
```

Without knowing your use case I don't know if this will work.

Comment: This works great, actually, getting me all the spans I was looking for, however I can't get just the text held inside the tag. I could use regex to extract it, but I feel it would be better to use their methods for that. What would you use to get specifically the text inside?

Comment: Honestly I'm a bit of beginner myself, I would just play with the strings. There's certainly a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
names = [item["class"] for item in page.find_all('span',class_="h6 m-0" )]
```

can you please be more specific about what problem you face

but this should work fine for you

Comment: How is this answer different from one posted by @bill ?

Comment: well actually i was just answering when it when bill too posted an answer to it