# How do I pull the div attributes out of these lines with beautiful soup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm using bs4 to pull the html of a webpage and the splitting each line into a list so I can pull the ones I want. (not sure if this step makes the next ones impossible by changing the data type, if so what would be a better way of doing this step?)

Once I have this narrowed list, I'm left with individual list elements looking like this:

*ignore the space after the first **<**, I couldn't get this to show otherwise*

```
< div class="row srpVehicle hasVehicleInfo" data-bodystyle="SUV" data-cpo="False" data-engine="V8 engine" data-extcolor="Red" data-extcolorcode="" data-fueltype="Gasoline Fuel" data-intcolor="Jet Black" data-intcolorcode="" data-make="Chevrolet" data-model="Tahoe" data-modelcode="1123706" data-mpgcity="16" data-mpghwy="20" data-msrp="0" data-name="2020 Chevrolet Tahoe LT" data-price="58995" data-stocknum="32948" data-trans="Automatic" data-trim="LT" data-vehicleid="0" data-vehicletype="new" data-vin="1G555555555" data-year="2020" id="srpVehicle-1GNS555513555">
```

I want to extract each of these data points; data-bodystyle, data-engine, data-model, etc. and put them into a dictionary to be converted to json later.

output example:

```
{'data-bodystyle':'SUV',
    'data-engine':'V8',
    'data-model':'Tahoe'}
```

Is there an easier way to accomplish this with bs4 methods? Currently when I get the  narrowed down, I use string split and some other manipulation to pull the data points but this doesn't seem to work efficiently.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get content from certain tags with certain attributes using BS4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62737471/get-content-from-certain-tags-with-certain-attributes-using-bs4)

Comment: Thank you very much sushanth. Your answer and this link were extremely helpful in guiding me to finding the solution. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every tag has `.attrs` property, where all attributes of the tag are stored. You can iterate over it like standard Python's dictionary:

```
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<div class="row srpVehicle hasVehicleInfo" data-bodystyle="SUV" data-cpo="False" data-engine="V8 engine" data-extcolor="Red" data-extcolorcode="" data-fueltype="Gasoline Fuel" data-intcolor="Jet Black" data-intcolorcode="" data-make="Chevrolet" data-model="Tahoe" data-modelcode="1123706" data-mpgcity="16" data-mpghwy="20" data-msrp="0" data-name="2020 Chevrolet Tahoe LT" data-price="58995" data-stocknum="32948" data-trans="Automatic" data-trim="LT" data-vehicleid="0" data-vehicletype="new" data-vin="1G555555555" data-year="2020" id="srpVehicle-1GNS555513555">'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

out = {}
div = soup.select_one('.hasVehicleInfo')
for a in div.attrs:
    if a.startswith('data-'):
        out[a.replace('data-', '')] = div[a]   # if you want to keep `data-...`, remove `.replace()`

# pretty print to screen:
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'bodystyle': 'SUV',
 'cpo': 'False',
 'engine': 'V8 engine',
 'extcolor': 'Red',
 'extcolorcode': '',
 'fueltype': 'Gasoline Fuel',
 'intcolor': 'Jet Black',
 'intcolorcode': '',
 'make': 'Chevrolet',
 'model': 'Tahoe',
 'modelcode': '1123706',
 'mpgcity': '16',
 'mpghwy': '20',
 'msrp': '0',
 'name': '2020 Chevrolet Tahoe LT',
 'price': '58995',
 'stocknum': '32948',
 'trans': 'Automatic',
 'trim': 'LT',
 'vehicleid': '0',
 'vehicletype': 'new',
 'vin': '1G555555555',
 'year': '2020'}
```